Позиционирование элемента относительно правого верхнего угла
public void DefaultMode()
{      
    this.TimeLeft.Name = "timeLabel";

    this.TimeLeft.Anchor = (AnchorStyles.Top | AnchorStyles.Right);

    this.TimeLeft.Text = "0";
    this.TimeLeft.Font = new Font("Arial", 16);
    this.TimeLeft.TextAlign = ContentAlignment.MiddleCenter;
    
    this.TimeLeft.BorderStyle = BorderStyle.FixedSingle;
    this.TimeLeft.BackColor = Color.Red;

    this.TimeLeft.Size = new Size(200, 30);
    
    this.TimeLeft.Location = new Point(this.Width, 0);

    this.Controls.Add(TimeLeft);
}

Пытался поставить элемент TimeLeft в верхний правый угол, поставил точку относительно которой элемент будет иметь позицию в верхний правый угол. По итогу элемент располагается относительно лево верхнему углу элемента. Атрибут Anchor не помогает.

Всё прекрасно работает. Разве что Point(this.Width приведёт к тому, что контрол будет за пределами родительского.

this.TimeLeft.Location = new Point(this.Width - this.TimeLeft.Width, 0); При абсолютном позиционировании анчоры смысла не имеют, можно убрать.
